# Convert binary to decimals?

Tags: c#-4.0, binary

In C#, if I was to read in "3 32-bit floating point numbers" as a `byte[]` from a binary file `Stream`, how would I extract the 3 decimals? Looking for the code to read the data and then extract the 3 decimals. Assume the file only contains the "3 32-bit floating point numbers".

Comment: Your file has 3 float-point numbers, each one with 32-bit? You want to read this numbers and then extract only the decimal fraction of each one, like the .97 in 8.97? Is that you want?

Comment: No, pull out all three numbers as they are in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `BitConvert.ToSingle`:

```
// numbers to read
var count = 3; 

// read file bytes into a buffer
var buffer = new byte[sizeof(float) * count];
var stream = File.OpenRead("path/to/file");
stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
stream.Dispose();

var numbers = Enumerable
        .Range(0, count)
        // read 32 bits from buffer and convert to float
        .Select(index => BitConverter.ToSingle(buffer, index * sizeof(float)))
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: Yep - works. I was trying to do `new decimal(data.Take(4))` but it was only working for some of the value being imported. Single seems to work better! Thanks.